# Unable to echo symbols; also unable to see symbols within code

Tags: php, vba, encoding, utf-8

The following Symbols prints well in an MS Excel spreadsheet when outputting using VBA:

```
Sub print_chrw_sub()
    Dim a1
    a1 = "&H27E6"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value = ChrW(a1)

    Dim a2
    a2 = "&H27E7"
    ActiveCell.Offset(2).Value = ChrW(a2)

End Sub
```

Output:

```
⟦
⟧
```

However, when I am using the symbols in a PHP code, the sybols look like square blocks within the code as well as on a web browser - also in the current usage above. Example:

```
<?php
    echo $str1 = "⟧"
?>
```

I am using UTF-8 encoding.

On the flip side the following sybols are printing correctly in PHP code as well as on a web browser:

> chrW(&H22A4)

Output:

```
⊤
```

---

> chrW(&H22A5)

Output:

```
⊥
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean that you see a [Right square bracket](http://unicode-table.com/en/005D/) instead of a [Mathematical right white square bracket](http://unicode-table.com/en/27E7/)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your message. I am not sure whether it is the right square bracket that you have pointed at. Here is an image of the output that I wish to get. [Desired_Bracket](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=02c4028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character you refer as `chrW(&H27E7)` is known as the [Mathematical right white square bracket](http://unicode-table.com/en/27E7/) (or `U+27E7`).

When it is displayed in Excel, the font displayed is probably Calibri or Arial, but these fonts actually don't support this character.
And that's where [font substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution) steps in: to provide a font wich will correctly handle the character.
If you look at [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%9F%A7+-+MATHEMATICAL+RIGHT+WHITE+SQUARE+BRACKET+%28U%2B27E7%29), you will see which fonts on your system actually support `U+27E7`. On my system there is only two: Cambria Math and Segoe UI Symbol.

If you see a square symbol (□), it means that font substitution didn't work correctly. For the PHP source, it is not very important, because the correct character will actually be there (provided the encoding is set up correctly).

For the HTML code, you should consider setting a font which you know support this character, be keep in mind that local fonts (the ones installed) differ vastly between two systems. You may want to use the [CSS font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face) to provide a web font.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to see the correct symbol in the code when I changed the font to "Cambria Math". However, I am still not sure how to implement a PHP code to print the symbol correctly on a web browser.

Comment: @user3051619 Could you show a screenshot of what is displayed? Have you tried in another browser? Also, are you sure that the web page is displayed as utf-8?